Chemformula subscript after escaped text
I am using the string "3AMP" to denote a complex ion. It needs to be escaped so that the "3" is not subscripted. However, if more than one such ion occurs per-formula unit (e.g. (3AMP)2) I run into problems. The document
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{(AMP)2}

\ch{( "3AMP" )2}

\ch{( "3AMP" )_2}

\end{document}

produces this output:

The first line (without escaping) works as expected, but automatic subscripting no longer works after the escaped text. I can get around it with \ch{( "3AMP" )$_2$}, but at that point the package starts to become more trouble than its worth. Is there any cleaner solution?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

You'll need to 'stop' the scanner: I'd use {}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{(AMP)2}

\ch{( "3AMP" )2}

\ch{( "3AMP" ){}_2}

\end{document}


Nice, I tried using braces at different places, but I didn't manage to get it. It seems that \ch{( "3AMP" ){}2} also works (without _).

Coo! From the doc, it seemed like chemformula also breaks on spaces. Any idea why that didnt happen here?

Not sure it is the best way, but you can define a macro to hold the name
\newcommand{\myion}{3AMP}
\ch{(\myion)2}

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}


\begin{document}

\ch{(AMP)2}

\ch{( "3AMP" )$\sb{2}$}

\newcommand{\myion}{3AMP}
\ch{(\myion)2}

\end{document}


